# how to create labels for data in donut chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, d3.js, label

I have a donut chart which updates data on click. I want to add labels to the same data. I am currently using the *d3.js* javascript library.
[Here is my code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5Znf/)

What I don't understand it how to add labels to segments of the donut chart?

Answer (score 22):

You have to use the [arc.centroid](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-arc_centroid) function. Take a look at the following examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/GQDUS/
- http://bl.ocks.org/2295263
- http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/9/
- http://blog.stephenboak.com/2011/08/07/easy-as-a-pie.html

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html or http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2295263. Check the code and you should be able to answer this question fairly easy. Have fun!

Comment: Thank u for your response.But that in that example the data is not updating itself plus a new plugin needs to be included.I have modified my code and the fiddle is :http://jsfiddle.net/RNuee/2/. I have swapped the data for update.the labels are there.I just need help in the arctween function which redraws arcs with fresh data.can u plz look into it.

Comment: The link you posted is dead.