# d3js Redistributing labels around a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to create a donut chart with labels on the outside. Using some trigonometry based on the centroids of each slice of the pie, I position the labels.

```
g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "percentage")
        .append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d)
                { 
                    var c = arc.centroid(d);
                    var x = c[0];
                    var y = c[1];
                    var h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
                    return "translate(" + (x/h * obj.labelRadius) +  ',' + (y/h * obj.labelRadius) +  ")"; 
                }
            ) 
            .attr("dy", ".4em")
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) 
                {
                    return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ? "end" : "start";
                }
            )
            .text(function(d) { return d.data.percentage+"%"; });
```

What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is to rearrange labels that are outside the edges of the pie chart, to prevent overlaps.

[image]

One of the ways I have tried to solve the problem is to define set "anchor points", where labels can be positioned, guaranteeing that they will no overlap. Problem is mapping the centroids to the anchors and preserving some sense of visual correspondence between the slices and the labels (Specially difficult when slices are slim).

[image]

Image above shows the possible location of the anchors (centroids of the slices shown). With these positions it is impossible to have an overlap.

Adding complexity to the problem is the fact that when labels (they're horizontal) are close to the top or bottom of the pie, they are more easily overlapped, than when they are on the right or left of the pie.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

[EDIT] Following the suggestion of meetamit, I implemented the following:

```
.attr("dy", function(d)
{
    var c = arc.centroid(d);
        var x = c[0];
        var y = c[1];
        var h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
        var dy = y/h * obj.labelRadius; 
    dy=dy*fontSizeParam*.14/heightParam);
    return (dy)+"em";
})
```

It helps a bit, and gives some room to the labels, still looking for a solution that will cover all cases though...

Comment: Could you put up an example of what you have so far on jsfiddle?

Comment: I added an image for clarity. I haven't implemented in code the "anchor" solution, as I've worked out on paper various cases where it can fail.

Comment: I see.  Indeed, you have a difficult problem, and one that really has little to do with d3 per se: you are seeking a general algorithm for the placement of labels on your graph.  Can you make any assumptions?  Eg, if all the pieces were as little as the green and yellow ones, there would simply be no good way to fit all the labels in?  What about showing the label only on hover for pieces that are below a certain size?

Comment: Thanks Jonah. Hover is ruled out as they are touch devices and won't support interactivity. Some possible assumptions: No more than 12 slices allowed, so there is always a possible arrangement of the labels without overlap. Mapping the positions and keeping visual coherence is the problem here.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help.  I did find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506819/how-to-create-labels-for-data-in-donut-chart-using-d3-js.  Also you might consider making the text perpendicular to the tangent lines of the circle, so it expands out like flower petals.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will have a look at those links. Will continue to break my head for a working solution.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with the scheme you mocked up. You can take it a step further, by varying the local vertical positioning (i.e. the `dy` attribute) as a function of the label's y position. I.e. the labels at the top would be bottom-aligned with their anchor points, while the labels at the bottom will be top-aligned (as they more-or-less already are in your comp). Labels at the middle would be middle-aligned. It's just an interpolation... Finally, if you color the label to match the color of the pie segment it points to, there will be a very strong association.

Comment: meetamit, I tried your solution and it does help! I have a little bit more room to wiggle, thanks. I think I will implement some kind of sorting where there is one big slice-small slice-big slice-small slice, etc... There are still cases where this will fail though

Comment: Could you not rotate your labels to stick radially outward?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create two arcs? one for the chart, and one for the labels?

```
// first arc used for drawing the pie chart
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

// label attached to first arc
g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });

// second arc for labels
var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius + 20)
  .innerRadius(radius + 20);

// label attached to second arc
g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good, pragmatic [d3.js](http://d3js.org)-based solution by programmer John Williams presented here:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/

It should work well for cases with reasonable restrictions, e.g. a maximum of 12 labels as discussed above. There are also pointers in the article to more advanced algorithms, but this simple approach may actually, when used with sufficient label-content constraints, give results that have a more orderly visual appearance than other methods would yield.