# How to fix the label alignment on pie chart in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/VYH5QbO99ZbMkvc2D4Fe?p=preview

As I add more and more categories, these labels overlap and I can't see anything

Is there a better way to align labels?

Thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155194/d3js-redistributing-labels-around-a-pie-chart) may help. In general, you'll have to implement something yourself to distribute the labels though, for example by using the force layout.

Answer (score 0):

I rather moved to using NVD3 and created pie charts

The demo and code is availale http://plnkr.co/edit/qJnZzBS4ZOUtD2q9FV11?p=preview