# doughnut chart with axis information

Tags: d3.js

I would like to draw dougnut charts with axis and y axis headings like given below
even though the x-axis info is constant and y -axis depends on the tsv file input. I had tied to utiize the script from n (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305337 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3888852/ to woirk it out . but i was unable to

```
    Place1                      Place 2                        Place3
Season1     Season2         Season1     Season2         Season1     Season2
```

Name1   Chart1  Chart2       Chart1     chart2                Chart1    chart2 
Name2   Chart1  Chart2       Chart1     chart2                Chart1    chart2 
Name3   Chart1  Chart2       Chart1     chart2                Chart1    chart2

My tsv file looks like this

State   color 1 color 2 color 3 color 4 source
S1  310504  552339  259034  450818  a1
S2  52083   85640   42153   74257   a1
S1  515910  828669  362642  601943  a1
S2  202070  343207  157204  264160  a1
S1  2704659 4499890 2159981 3853788 a1
S2  358280  587154  261701  466194  a1
S1  211637  403658  196918  325110  a2
S2  59319   99496   47414   84464   a2
S1  36352   50439   25225   75569   a2
S2  1140516 1938695 925060  1607297 a2
S1  740521  1250460 557860  919876  a2
S2  87207   134025  64011   124834  a2

Comment: Hi! All it took was a bit of googling... Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/GQDUS/) or even better, another [SO question in the same line...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506819/how-to-create-labels-for-data-in-donut-chart-using-d3-js)

Comment: thank you for the reply. Actually i dont want to display the data value but instead i want to write a name and then 6 doughnut chart representing 6 data values for the same name. and in total i have 15 names